# shape of the result matrix for multiplying 2 arrays in numpy

Tags: numpy

[shape of result matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWBGq.png)

matrix A is 3X3
array B is 3X1
so the shape of AXB should be 3X1.
the numpy calculation shows it as 1X3
where am i wrong?

I was expecting the shape as 3X1

Comment: Please post text as [formatted text](/help/formating), not a screenshot

Comment: `B` has a shape of `(3,)`, which isn't the same as a shape of `(3, 1)`

Comment: Also don't use `np.matrix` https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html#numpy-matrix

Comment: For `A` being (3,3) `ndarray`, `A@B` would be (3,) shape.  But `A` is `np.matrix` so the result is also `np.matrix`, with added leading dimension (1,3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for `matmul/@` (and `dot`) is written with `ndarray` in mind:

With (3,3) and (3,):

```
In [99]: A= np.arange(9).reshape(3,3); b=np.arange(3)
```

`matmul` is (3,) (so would `np.dot`)):

```
In [100]: A@b
Out[100]: array([ 5, 14, 23])
```

But with `np.matrix`, it appears the result (3,) is "promoted" to `matrix`), which by default adds a leading dimension:

```
In [101]: np.matrix(A)@b
Out[101]: matrix([[ 5, 14, 23]])
```

Originally `*` was defined to be matrix multiplication for `np.matrix` (as it is in MATLAB):

```
In [102]: np.matrix(A)*b
ValueError: shapes (3,3) and (1,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

That tried to promote `b` to `np.matrix`, resulting in a (3,3) with (1,3) => error.

`np.dot` of the same behaves like `@`:

```
In [103]: np.dot(np.matrix(A),b)
Out[103]: matrix([[ 5, 14, 23]])
```

To use `*` we have to make the 2nd (3,1) shape:

```
In [104]: np.matrix(A)*np.matrix(b).T
Out[104]: 
matrix([[ 5],
        [14],
        [23]])

In [105]: np.matrix(b).T
Out[105]: 
matrix([[0],
        [1],
        [2]])
```

In short using `np.matrix` with `matmul/@` complicates things, producing a result that doesn't quite fit the documentation.